# Samba doesn't ask for a password

Tags: linux, samba, samba4

I'm trying to set up Samba on my home server but it doesn't ask for a password.
What did I do wrong?

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
security = user
map to guest = Bad User
wins support = no
dns proxy = no

[share]
path = /media/storage/share
guest ok = no
valid users = @securedgroup, @usergroup
browsable = yes
writable = yes

[admin]
path = /media/storage/admin
valid users = @securedgroup
guest ok = no
browsable = yes
writable = yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, mainly because you have this: 'map to guest = Bad User', you haven't created any Samba users. Try reading this: 
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Standalone_Server

You don't actually need that line because you have 'map to guest = no' set on both shares (and you don't actually need them, they are default settings).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the

```
valid users
```

option to the list of users not groups may help.